# iw use Regulatory.bin from /snapd/core instead /lib/crda

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, snap, iw

I modified frequency in */lib/crda/regulatory.bin* using crda scripts but unfortunately *iw* from version 5.4.5 for some reason use file */snapd/core/8689/lib/crda/regulatory.bin* which is unmodificable even with su priviliges.

How can I change *regulatory.bin* from snaps folder, or is there a way to force *iw* to use regulatory.bin from */lib/crda* ?

Comment: snap is supposed to be self sufficient. so the reason it uses its own snap's data is to not depend on anything else. You could recompile/backport iw from ubuntu eoan to get a 5.3 version (or focal for 5.4), instead of using iw provided by snap.

Comment: so is there any easy way to remove iw from snap and install it manually?

Comment: else sorry, the way is not easy for everybody. even if it's for ubuntu, you can follow this: https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingTutorial

Comment: i dont really need newest version of iw, what I want to achieve is to remove iw from snap (somehow) so i could install it mannualy from here https://github.com/CTU-IIG/802.11p-iw/tree/its-g5_v3-patchset1

Comment: so it just enough to execute sudo snap remove iw and then install it from github as normal package?

Comment: you're using Ubuntu. why would you install from github? I really don't follow you. iw is a standard package. "i dont really need newest version of iw" vs "from here github.com/CTU-IIG/802.11p-iw/tree/its-g5_v3-patchset1"

Comment: Ok so i will explain it precisely. I need to change frequency of my wifi card from 5735 - 5835 to 5835 - 5935. To do that I need to change my regulatory.bin file but right now I can't do this cause iw is inside /snap partition. I was able to change frequency easily on ubuntu 14.04 where iw wasn't yet standard package (that why I was using 802.11p version). So right now I want to force ubuntu to remove iw package from my ubuntu and to be able to install it by my own.

Comment: so remove as you said and add the ubuntu package? then you can use dpkg-divert (check man page) to be sure upgrades won't lose your changes